# Set min KeepAliveTimeout only for one subdomain in NGINX?

Tags: php, nginx

In my project, one subdomain handles a process that takes a **huge amount of data into the memory** so I want to close the connection immediately after serving the result to the user.
I think NGINX **KeepAlive timeout** can handle this situation.
So is there any possibility to give min KeepAliveTimeout for a particular subdomain only?

Server: NGINX
Script: PHP7.0

Comment: why not try to add that directive between `server` scope

Comment: I am a beginner in handling NGINX, I don't know is it possible to add inside `server` scope. Currently, it's in the nginx.conf file.

Comment: I recommend You to set that timeout on php configurations, if it's php-fpm check `pool.d` folder and define it per php process

Comment: read about this: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive

Comment: @num8er but I want to set in a subdomain only. Is it possible to do with php-fpm

Comment: 1. Create upstream as in example with keepalive, 2. Proxy pass php handling to upstream